# Insert from java into SQL Server appends 'null'

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert values into a SQL database from within Java. This works fine, except for some of the values. Eg, when I insert "foo" it appends null at the start so it becomes "nullfoo". If I insert the same statement in SQL Server Management Studio this doesn't happen.

To be sure: I print the string before inserting it and it reads "foo".

My insert code:

```
statement.execute("INSERT INTO " + settings.getProperty("table") + " VALUES ('" + value1+ "', '" + value2 + "', '" + value3 + "')");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're concatenating values into the SQL statement. If any of those references (`value1`, `value2` etc) are null, then those will be converted into the string "null" as part of concatenation.

The correct fix for this is *not* to change the way you're doing validation - it's to *stop putting the values into the SQL statement itself*. Use `PreparedStatement` with parameterized SQL and set parameter values instead.

Benefits:

- You won't get "null" inserted any more
- You won't be vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) any more (you are now)
- When inserting non-text data you won't need to worry about problematic conversions (this is particularly relevant for date/time fields)
- Your code will be clearer, as you'll be separating the code (SQL) from the data (parameter values)
- Your prepared statement query plan can be cached by the server, so it *may* perform faster

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I made sure though that the references are not null (by printing the query before executing it), still it appends null at the start. I'll have a look at PreparedStatement in the meantime

Comment: @Freek8: Please try assigning the value to a local variable first, and show us the log of that variable. I'm 99% sure you're just misdiagnosing this - but using parameterized SQL is *definitely* the way forward anyway.

Comment: I´ll use the parameterized way. Just out of curiosity, if I assign it to a local variable and print that it reads:
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', '', '', '', '2129678021')

Comment: @Freek8: And how are you then diagnosing the "null"? Is it perhaps in your *reading* code?

Comment: I tried doing it with preparedStatement (see question) but it still gives me null - values :/

Comment: @Freek8: You need to tell us more about what you're doing then, including what you mean by "it still gives me null" - how are you looking at the data?

Comment: If I execute the statements as shown in the Proposed Solution, and then  check SQL Server Mgmt Studio for the newly added records, I see fields such as: "nullValue1". I double checked my complete code and nowhere do I use null.

Comment: @Freek8: Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. It sounds like `value1` or `value2` may already have the `null` part. Are there any triggers involved on the database?

Comment: @Freek8: Please show a complete example which *doesn't* need any external data. Things like "executes some formatting on the string" suggests that that could *very easily* be where the problem lies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5050/discussion-between-freek8-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Freek8: No, chat doesn't work for me with the way I work. But I strongly suggest that you write a short, complete, self-contained console app which just inserts a row in the database with hardcoded data. If that *doesn't* add the "null" then that strongly suggests the problem *isn't* in the database access, and you can move to looking elsewhere.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/71yNNWKA Here is my code. If I hardcode it there is no problem so I guess something must be going wrong in the non-db part

Comment: @Freek8: Make it shorter: get rid of *all* the formatting code. Just hard code literal values. This is how you should be working out what's wrong: isolate one piece of your code at a time. You don't want to test "formatting + database access"... you want to test formatting, and you want to test database access, each completely independently.

Comment: I did that, just write an insert into-statement by hand without variables. It works. Strange thing: when I change into: statement2.setString(1, "blablabla"); the "blablabla" doesn't show up in mgmt studio anymore.

Comment: @Freek8: Okay, your two statements appear to contradict each other - you say it works, but then you say that the value doesn't show up...

Comment: woops, too many edits screwed up that comment. I managed to make it work, apparently my code was not resetting the database properly, and for some reason I couldn't insert the statements anymore. Now that it properly drops the table and recreates it everything's okay. Thanks a lot for your help Skeet, apparently the changes were helping but the results didn't go through to SSMS

Answer (score 1):

You should use variable binding in your SQL

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/bind-variables-usage-parameterized-queries-in-sql-server/

It's easier to check for errors.

In your case you are probably adding null+"foo" so you get nullfoo.